# Routing external traffic through VPN tunnel

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, vps, wireguard

I need assistance creating a ip route that forces traffic coming into my VPS's public IP on port 27016 or 3202 to my Wireguard VPN tunnel.

For context, I created this VPS to allow me to expose my Steam game server to the public with a static IP. I have successfully connected the game server to the VPS via Wireguard; all traffic from the game server to the WAN is being routed through the VPS, however, inbound traffic (like server query) is not being routed to the VPN and therefore into the game server. This was confirmed by running Wireshark on the game server.

The game server is a Windows Server 22 VM hosted on Proxmox. The VPS is a DigitalOcean droplet running Ubuntu 22.10.

This is what I believe the route should look like, not entirely sure how to do it properly:

```
publicIP (eth0 interface) > VPN Tunnel (wg0 interface; 192.168.69.1) > VPN peer (192.168.69.2) > Game server (10.11.12.150)
```

**IPs**

- VPS Public IP: 162.243.164.xxx
- VPN Gateway: 192.168.69.1
- Game server VPN IP: 192.168.69.2
- Game server local IP: 10.11.12.150

**VPS Wireguard Config**

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = KEY
Address = 192.168.69.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = KEY
AllowedIPs = 192.168.69.2
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

**VPS IP Route**

```
default via 162.243.164.1 dev eth0 proto static 
10.10.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.0.5 
10.116.0.0/20 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.116.0.2 
162.243.164.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 162.243.164.xxx 
192.168.69.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.69.1
```

**VPS IP ADDR**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 6a:24:cf:89:d5:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        altname enp0s3
        altname ens3
        inet 162.243.164.xxx/24 brd 162.243.164.255 scope global eth0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet 10.10.0.5/16 brd 10.10.255.255 scope global eth0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::6824:cfff:fe89:d504/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether ce:21:97:e6:06:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        altname enp0s4
        altname ens4
        inet 10.116.0.2/20 brd 10.116.15.255 scope global eth1
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::cc21:97ff:fee6:614/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    5: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/none 
        inet 192.168.69.1/24 scope global wg0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**TCPDUMP** command: tcpdump -i any -n udp and port 27016; result is from querying publicip:27016 one time.

```
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
18:10:47.290457 eth0  In  IP 162.55.52.17.52424 > 162.243.164.xxx.27016: UDP, length 25
18:10:55.926653 eth0  In  IP 141.94.81.117.35441 > 162.243.164.xxx.27016: UDP, length 25
```

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciate as I am still learning.

**Additional Info**

Below is the Wireguard config on the game server (client/peer)

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = KEY
Address = 192.168.69.2/24
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = KEY
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = VPS PUBLIC IP
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried appending the following IPTables to PostUp on the VPS with no luck:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 27016 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.69.1:27016; iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -p udp --dport 27016 -j ACCEPT;
```

I tried creating an ip route & rule by running the following commands:

```
ip route add table 80 192.168.69.0/24 dev wg0 src 192.168.69.1
ip rule add ipproto udp dport 27016 lookup 80
```

No change in result.